# SLD styling based on Cql filter result

Tags: sld, cql-filter

I am using Geoserver 2.4.4 with a PostGIS database.

I have 2 layers configured, one of them represents some polygons.
I am trying to put a label inside the polygon with the number of the features of the second layer inside the bounding box of the first layer.

Eg: number of cities in a State.

I am wondering if it is possible to achieve this only with SLD styling of the layer.

I am looking at ways to apply Point Stacker function to achieve this, but I can't find a good example or documentation.

Comment: I obtained the same behavior by creating an additional layer, with some processing on the other layers in Business Logic.